# Why Default Applications Do Not Have .tex Editor in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, latex, ide

System: Ubuntu 14.04 on Macbook Air 2013-mid.

[image]

No feature to set the default editor for .txt documents and for .tex documents. 
Also, no possibility to change it by pressing *Open With* and choosing the application.

---

How can you set the default application of .tex documents in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: This looks like a rant disguised as a question.

Comment: You are asking for .tex files or .txt files ?

Comment: .tex but took there also .txt as an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## How to set a default application for random file extensions

- Do a right click on a single file and select **Properties** from the context menu.
- In the properties window select the tab **Open with**
- Select an application and choose **Set as default**

[image]

Comment: Why cannot Ubuntu overload things? Why not to have small tickbox in OpenWith where you can say *open always this kind of files with this application*? Why clutter applications in different menus like *Defaults* and *SecondClick>OpenWith*? Confusing philosophy.

Comment: This is handled by the file manager, in this case nautilus. So if you feel it should be simpler then take up with Gnome as it's nothing Ubuntu has a part in.